# Unable to infer type when returning a function

Tags: typescript

I have two version s of the same function; for the first (`propEq` below), typescript can infer that the `key` argument can and should be a key of the object with type `T`.

For the second function (`propEq2` below), `key` has type `never`. If i provide the type arguments explicitly, it'll work without a problem. I'm guessing this is because the first part of `propEq2` only knows what type `T` will be once it's called, and I can see why that would be a problem. But even when I call it on an object, I still get the same error.

Is there any way for me to correctly type this kind of function?

```js
export const propEq = <T, K extends keyof T>(key: K, equals: T[K], object: T) => object[key] === equals;
export const propEq2 = <T, K extends keyof T>(key: K, equals: T[K]) => (object: T) => object[key] === equals;
```

Answer (score 2):

So the issue which you are facing is - by design how TS works. Type inference is done from left to right, from top to bottom. Also common sense here shows that your requirement is not possible as if you say `K extends keyof T` then `K` is `never` until `T` is known, as when you set key you have no object yet provided then at the type level you have exactly:

```
type K = keyof unknown; // K is never
```

That is why if you provide firstly `K` you need to provide `T` explicitly before `K`, then `keyof T` can be evaluated to the meaningful type.

Also you can do that in the revert way, so declare key and value as first and set the requirement to the object after, so in other way round. Consider below:

```
const propEq = <K extends PropertyKey, V>(key: K, equals: V) => 
<T extends Record<K, V>>(object: T) => object[key] === equals;

propEq3('a', 1)({a: 2}) // yes correct
propEq3('a', 1)({a: 'str'}) // error as it should, `a` has different type
propEq3('a', 1)({b: 1}) // error as it should, there is no `a` in object
```

What is done here:

- `<K extends PropertyKey, V>` we say `K` is some property type, and `V` is anything
- Both `K` and `V` are infered from `key` and `equals` arguments
- `object` is restricted to be `T extends Record<K, V>`, so we allow for comparison of only object which has this key with this type of value

Above solution is quite nice, as we don't restrict our equation to single type, but our newly created `propEq` can be used with any object with wanted key and value type.